# Creating a Web2.0 application with Maven(or other build tools)

Tags: javascript, maven, web-applications, build

**Background:**
I've been building web apps and web sites for many years, but each time I tend to start from scratch as each project has different requirements.  However, this has me building my workflow from scratch as well.  At this point, I'm about ready to settle on something a little more standard.

But what exactly is that *standard*?  Being a JAVA developer by nature, I'm drawn to tools like Maven.  And I've seen some work in the community for better Javascript support in Maven (javascript-maven-tools, javascript-maven-plugin, and others).  But is this the best way to do it?  I tried for a while to find a good WEB2.0 client/ajax-app maven-archetype to no avail.

I'm going to want to use tools in my workflow including JSLint [[http://www.jslint.com]], JSUnit [[http://jsunit.net/]] for testing, Documentation with things such as JSDoc Toolkit [[http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/]].  Compression and Framework inclusion would be nice too.

So, at this point, I'm even stumped at the the basic ways to start my app.  What should a directory structure look like?  For a pure client/frontend app (so no controllers, etc), do i just have a single webapp directory?

I guess I'm at that point where I'm questioning "my religion" with webapps.  And after talking to everyone I know, I figured it was time for me to open it up to a hive-mind far smarter than my own.

> Note. This is a question I also wrote
>   about in general on my site at
>   [[http://blog.jbjonesjr.com/?p=283]]
>   , but no one every cares about it
>   there.

Thanks for the help, I look forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've started a couple of plugins ([this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-plugin/) and [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jslint-plugin/)) on Codehaus that facilitate the use of Maven for building JavaScript applications following Maven's goal oriented approach. I want to do more of this including the provision of a Surefire-compatible unit testing plugin and a minification plugin that leverages assembles. Take a look at what I've done so far and feel free to help out!

I'm also considering providing a JavaScript DSL for Maven using [Polyglot Maven](http://polyglot.sonatype.org/). A colleague kindly pointed out that JavaScript programmers will probably want to express their poms using JavaScript, not XML. In addition they probably won't want the learning curve of Maven. A JavaScript DSL could facilitate that.